# Using FileProvider with getExternalMediaDirs() - "failed to find configured root Android/media"

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent, android-fileprovider

I'm using getExternalMediaDirs() when creating a file to store a photo, and using FileProvider to pass this file to the camera intent.

The reason for using FileProvider is to overcome a FileUriExposedException that I am seeing with Android 7.

Here's a cut-down version of the code:

```
File[] directories = getExternalMediaDirs();
filesDir = directories[directories.length > 1 ? 1 : 0];

if (!filesDir.exists())
{
    if (!filesDir.mkdirs())
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to create file in: " + filesDir);
        return null;
    }
}

photoFile = new File(filesDir, "photoXXX.jpg");

final Intent captureImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, FILE_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, photoFile);
captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

I have tested this on a number of Android 5 and 6 devices (there's different code for Android 4.x), but I have just received a crash report from an Android 6 device:

**Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/3166-3436/Android/media/[package name]/photoXXX.jpg**

file_paths.xml:

```
<paths >
    <files-path name="internal_images" path="Pictures/"/>
    <external-path name="external_images0" path="Pictures/"/>
    <external-path name="external_images1" path="Android/media"/>
    <external-path name="external_images2" path="Android/data"/>
    <cache-path name="cached_images" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Android manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

This same code works on 2 other Android 6 devices I'm using, and is storing data in the Android/media sub-directory.   Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I'm wondering if it's not possible to use FileProvider with getExternalMediaDirs()?

Comment: `/storage/3166-3436` points to the SD card. FileProvider cannot serve files from there. Better put them on external memory.

Comment: @greenapps - is the issue here: filesDir = directories[directories.length > 1 ? 1 : 0];    i'd taken this as recommended elsewhere, but in reality is this referencing the SD card?

Comment: Well show the path(s) to begin with and we will know. Maybe you have to choose [0]. I never saw that function before but it looks like getExternalFilesDirs(). The second item would be the sd card. The first external memory.

Comment: @greenapps - thanks for swift reply.  I've decided to test all directories returned by getExternalMediaDirs() using Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(), and if available, choose the first that isn't removable.  Strange thing is that my test platform for Android 6 does have external storage, although it's mounted as "Adoptable Storage" which is probably where the problem lies as this may well work with FileProvider, whereas the crash came from a different configuration?!?  Time will tell.

Comment: Please show the paths like i asked before.

Comment: I think you dont have to test anything. Just take the first one.

Comment: `my test platform for Android 6 does have external storage`. You are saying nothingl Every device has external storage. And if you put an sdcard in it it has removable strage too. In 6.0 and above the user can decide to add the sdcard to external memory. Or just keep it as portable sdcard.

Comment: `reason for using FileProvider is I understand this is necessary to overcome permissions issues with Android 7.`. No. To prevent a file uri exposed exception or something like that.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for the replies - I expect you are correct in that the first directory returned is the primary storage and not going to be removable SD, so I don't need to test.  I'm not sure what you want when you ask for the paths.  The crash was reported via Firebase Crash reporting, so I don't have more info.   You are correct about the Android 7 issue, I'll edit the initial question to reflect this.

Comment: With file.getAbsolutePath() you get the full parh. Those i wanted to know.

Comment: @greenapps  Now I am confused.  I'm testing with an Android 4.4 device with removable SD card.  Using File[] directories = getExternalFilesDirs(), I get 2 directories returned.  directories[0] =  /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/ which I assume is the removable SD, and directories[1] = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ which looks like the non-removable external memory.  What I'm confused by is that FileProvider is working with /storage/sdcard1, and is FAILING with /storage/emulated/0   I'm now back to the start in my understanding of what's going on here.

Comment: Check if the user of the phone can change the default storage location for media.